# Cash State vs Fungible token in Corda

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda

Both  [Cash State](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.8/finance/contracts/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/Cash.kt) and [Fungible Token](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/contracts/states/FungibleToken.kt) can be used to represent money in Corda. Both can be issued , transferred(move) and redeemed (exit).

What is a more appropriate type to use for representing money on ledger?
Are there any pros , cons to useing either type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've talked on (slack.corda.net) on this issue and the short answer you've already found is that fungible tokens are a better tool for representing fungible assets like currencies.

We have a bootcamp on the tokens SDK on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAViczRAEyU

Here are some docs that we looked at on CorDapp concepts where you'll see that tokens are the recommended way to go: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.7/cordapp-advanced-concepts.html#the-demo-finance-cordapp

You can also find some clear developer samples on GitHub here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Tokens

Most of the difficulty is going to be modifying your state and just changing your flows a bit to deal with the tokens:

```java
            // Preparing the token type of the paying fiat currency
            Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(stockState.getCurrency());
            TokenType dividendTokenType = new TokenType(currency.getCurrencyCode(), currency.getDefaultFractionDigits());

            // Calculate the actual dividend paying to the shareholder
            BigDecimal yield = stockState.getDividend().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(claimNoticication.getAmount().getQuantity()));
            BigDecimal dividend = yield.multiply(stockState.getPrice()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(10.0, currency.getDefaultFractionDigits())));

            // Create the dividend state
            Amount<TokenType> dividendAmount = new Amount(dividend.longValue(), dividendTokenType);
```

source: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Tokens/stockpaydividend/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/stockpaydividend/flows/ClaimDividendReceivable.java#L127

Comment: For anyone else with this dilemma, The Cash state I mentioned above is part of a of the finance cordapp, which as per the docs is just a sample. Its not recommended that those classes be used as is in a serious production project. The token SDK is the way to go as David has mnetioned above.  https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.7/cordapp-advanced-concepts.html#the-demo-finance-cordapp